# Well-defined OLS estimator

Tags: time-series, least-squares, assumptions

we know that OLS estimator $\beta = (X'X)^{-1}X'y$

Under what conditions of the matrix X, the OLS estimator is well-defined?

Comment: Have you tried looking this up in a textbook? Dozens if not hundreds of textbooks contain the answer.

Comment: the answer is that X is full-column rank matrix. Right? @RichardHardy

Comment: I do not remember. I would look this up in a textbook. There is probably some condition on $\mathbb{E}(X'X)$, too, if we are talking about time series (you have used the tag, so I assume we are), but again I would need to check.